# How to edit a web element attribute value in c# using selenium

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium-webdriver

example:

`<input type="text" id="cargo_q" autocomplete="off" value="5.5"/>`

How to change the value of "value" attribute using selenium web driver

Is there any method like: 
 IWebElement search_cargo =driver.FindElement(By.Id("cargo_q")));
  search_cargo.setAttribute(attribute name,attribute new value); "
?

Answer (score 1):

Use the JavascriptExecutor class:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver; //Driver is the WebDriver object
js.executeScript("document.getElementById('cargo_q').setAttribute('value', '10')");
```